# Why does my Epson WF-2530 keeps turning itself off and on

Tags: printer, epson-workforce

I have tried calling Epson support, to no avail. I keep getting disconnected. The printer just keeps cycling off and then turning itself on. It acts like it is scanning something and then stops. about 2 minutes later it turns itself off and starts the cycle all over again. I have just unplugged it.

Comment: I'm guessing they're getting slammed over there which is why you keep getting disconnected. Lots of people are having the same problem. Enough that we've had like 10 questions from first-timers here. So far we don't have answers but.... Did you recently update the firmware on the device, or can you check which firmware the device is currently running?

Comment: If we can pin down a particular firmware that is causing this, that might be very, very helpful.

Comment: I did not recently update firmware. I will try to see what is being used and let you know.

Comment: I just checked the Epson site and they only list a firmware from June of this year that stipulates it should only be run on devices showing "Recovery Mode" on their screen.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a chat session with Epson. This is what they told me to do.
I am in the process of trying it.

1. Power OFF the printer
2. Power OFF the router
3. Power ON the printer
4. The printer should now start up normally to the home screen
5. From the control panel reset the printer to default settings
6. Power ON the router
7. Reconnect the printer to the network
8. Do not connect your printer to google cloud services for now.

Comment: That did not work for me.